# How to create my own window frame in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, window, frame

I want to remove the standard window frame and put my own one with my own buttons. How can I do this?

Something like this (just a sample, you get the idea).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [WPF Shell Integration Library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell):

> The custom chrome feature allows applications control over the outer
>   frame of the window so that WPF content can be drawn over the title
>   bar.

Answer (score 0):

you might try to hide the original window frame by changing the Windowstyle property and then drawing the buttons and stuff you need wherever you need them.

[MSDN on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx)